# ASP.NET MVC: Unauthenticated User Always Redirected to Login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

I've been trying to fix this for a week now, I tried everything that crossed my mind. I am creating web app using asp.net mvc 4 template. Problem is that I am always redirected to login page before I can't access any route without log in first. Not even register new user, which is absurd. I'm using simple membership and default Account controller and I even tried removing [Authorize] attribute from Account controller, but even then I'm redirected to login page. 
My Account controller looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
...
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

My web config is:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
   </authentication>
```

In chrome when I click on Register link, I get this error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in following action in the _Layout.cshtml file

```
<li>@Html.Action("BasicInfo", "Profile")</li>
```

which is calling ProfileController action BasicInfo, and the ProfileController is decorated with `Authorize` attribute which redirected action to login. Quite a stupid and misleading mistake... Once I checked if user is authenticated before this action everything was ok

Answer (score 1):

Is this being hosted on IIS? Have you checked the authentication type at that level?  If you're hosting it within Visual Studio, ensure you've checked the 'Allow Anonymous' authentication and 'Windows Authentication' setting at the project level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try checking your database connection string? 
I assume the problem could be with InitializeSimpleMembership Attribute which tries to find the valid connection to SQL Server but it seems it cannot find one.